# Numpy random number generators and lambda functions

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm trying to create a list of random variables `wtfuns` that I can call as: `wtfuns[i](size=1000)` to return a list of 1000 samples of the particular random variable. For this, I am using lambda functions as follows:

```
wtfuns = []
pvals = [0.3,0.5,0.7]
for p in pvals:
    wtfuns.append(('bernoulli p='+str(p),lambda **x: binom(p,**x)))

for i in range(3):
    print(wtfuns[i][1](size=1000).mean())
```

Output

```
0.686
0.684
0.706
```

That is, in the column `wtfuns[:,1]` I have the same binomial random variable with parameter 0.7. However,

```
for p in pvals:
    print(wtfuns[0][1](size=1000).mean())
```

produces

```
0.311
0.524
0.67
```

Somehow the p value is being passed to the lambda function by reference. What is going on? I'm completely confused.

Comment: `wtfuns.append(('bernoulli p='+str(p), lambda p=p, **x: binom(p,**x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your first definition captures a reference to `p`.  As `p` changes, the function changes.  The solution is to use a trick that turns the lambda into a closure:

```
    wtfuns.append(('bernoulli p='+str(p),lambda p=p,**x: binom(p,**x)))
```

The "p=p" thing captures the current value of p into a local, which carries with the function.